# Java bytecode, java Supplier and invokedynamic argument

Tags: java, java-8, bytecode, invokedynamic

I have this class, and I compile it.

```
package org.test;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Test {
    static String get() { return "!!"; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier<String> sup = Test::get;
        System.out.println(sup.get());
    }
}
```

Then, trying to look into it's bytecode, I get following beginning of `public static void main` function:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: invokedynamic #3,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:get:()Ljava/util/function/Supplier;
         5: astore_1
         6: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
```

Here we can see the invokedynamic call, which, if I understand correctly, creates anonymous instance of Supplier interface.
Passed to invokedynamic are two arguments, one is #3.
The second argument is 0. So, my first question is: what does 0 stand here for?

In constant pool #3 stands for `#3 = InvokeDynamic #0:#27 // #0:get:()Ljava/util/function/Supplier;`. There is reference to #27 in constant pool, but no reference to #0.
My second question is: what does #0 stand for here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#0` (which you can see in the comment next to the invokedynamic) is actually an index in the `BootstrapMethods` table. So the first question, the `0` actually refers to `#0`. And that in turn is the index of the BootstrapMethods table. Which provides a link between the `invokedynamic` call origin and the targeted method.

If you would decompile with `javap -c -v FileName`you will see the whole constant pool. (Which I am assuming you have done?). Here you should find a reference to `#X MethodHandle #y:#z IDDL.bootstrapDynamic`. That is the point where the BootstrapMethods table links to. The handle that the `#0` links to, should eventually resolve to a `static bootstrapDynamic()` method.

Comment: You mean `0: #32 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;` from `BootstrapMethods:` ? But it's an instruction, not value

Comment: @DmitryV. what value are you expecting?

Comment: I just can't interpret `InvokeDynamic #0:#27` in case of #0 being a reference to `#32 invokestatic ..yadayada..`